# Remove server from Server Topology list

Tags: topology

I have removed a server (Database server) from a SharePoint 2007 farm.
However the server still displays in the "Farm Topology" list.

Is there a way to remove the server to correct the Farm Topology list?

Thanks

Comment: How did you remove it?  (may be a stupid question but I'm going to ask anyway) Have you tried to remove it from the "servers in farm screen" in Central Administration?

Comment: I removed the content database from the web application (in central admin). Awesome, missed the Remove Server link. :D

Comment: Also found you can use SPServer.Delete() in PowerShell to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you literally answered your question yourself but I would say get your desired server using [Get-SPServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607694%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method and then delete it using [SPServer.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spserver.delete%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of SPServer class.

**However this blog is not recommending above solution as it can cause damages as expained,**

> If anybody is ever planning on Uninstalling/Removing a server from a
>   SharePoint 2007 Farm, do not go to “Servers in a farm” and click
>   “Remove Server” or directly uninstall SharePoint 2007 on the server
>   through Control Panel. This will cause failures in timer job status
>   and will cause some problems down the road. The best way to Uninstall
>   or Remove a server is as follows
>
> 1. Log on to the server you want to remove or uninstall from the farm,
> 2. Run the SharePoint Products and Technology Configuration Wizard,
> 3. Select “Disconnect from Farm” and click on next,
> 4. Click OK to continue the wizard,
> 5. The wizard will take you through the steps and you should be see the “Successful Message”,
>
> Now you can uninstall SharePoint 2007 and the server disconnected from
>   the Farm.

Taken from [Removing or Uninstalling server from topology](http://sharepointreporter.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/removinguninstalling-a-server-from-sharepoint-farm/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned it is a Database server (so SharePoint is not installed on the server) which was previously hosting content databases.  Thanks for the extra info. :)